# R: Index an array dynamically

Tags: r, arrays, indexing, dynamic

let A be an array, say

```
A <- array(1:9, dim = c(3,3))
```

and let idx be an index vector, say

```
idx <- c(1,2)
```

Then,

`A[idx]` gives me the first two elements in A, thus, it is different to `A[1,2]`.

How is the syntax for getting `A[1,2]` using the variable idx?

I tried a manual computation, i.e.

```
A[idx[1] + (idx[2]-1)*3]
```

but I am not interested in such a "hack".

Comment: `A[cbind(1, 2)]` would work, or `A[cbind(idx[1], idx[2])]`

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! I think the slight modification A[rbind(idx)] works for me the best, since this is not limited to two dimensions.